# Where can I see the css generated by NextJS sass in readable form?

Tags: css, sass, next.js

Is it possible to see the css output generated by the scss files in NextJS in a legible form in Visual Studio Code? I found bundled, minified, and unreadable, but wondered if there is a plugin or something that lets me see what my scss files are generating. Thanks.

Comment: CSS isn't "minified" like javascript. It just collapses the whitespace. You should be able to put the files from `.next/static/css` into any css formatter to expand them.

Comment: thanks for looking at this. There is no css folder in /static. Where else might it stash them?

Comment: If you're doing `next export` for SSG they should get copied to your `out` directory. Where did you find the bundled/minified files?

Comment: On a work computer - they had hidden a bunch of folders - can now see the css folder. Going to look for a css formatter to expand the files. Thanks for the info.

Comment: You can also temporarily disable minification in webpack: 
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/7494 then you can see the unminified css.

Comment: If you want to play with changes to the SASS code and see the effect on the generated CSS code, you may also use an online compiler such as https://beautifytools.com/scss-compiler.php